# Replace method and changing format?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using vba method Replace, and I need to change every "*/*" to ",". This looks like a simple task so I use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells.Replace What:="_/_", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

The problem is when one of cells has value like:

04_/_2018

And the result is:

4,2018

instead of:

04,2018

All of my cells in this workbook has text formating before and after aplying the code. My guess is that Excel in a process is changing the format to general for a moment and it cut offs not necessary for a number left zero.

I've tried to bypass this issue by changing parameters of the method (none of this worked) and changing the decimal separator from "," to ".". This helped when using find and replace by hand from  Excel, but when I record it and try to use as Macro it doesn't work. What can I do to prevent Excel from cutting off zeros in this scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `04,2018` then use `.Find/.FindNext` then replace+reconstruct the value before placing in the cell.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oRange = ws.UsedRange

    SearchString = "_/_"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        If Left(aCell.Value, 1) = 0 Then
            aCell.Value = "'" & Replace(aCell.Value, SearchString, ",")
        Else
            aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, SearchString, ",")
        End If

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                If Left(aCell.Value, 1) = 0 Then
                    aCell.Value = "'" & Replace(aCell.Value, SearchString, ",")
                Else
                    aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, SearchString, ",")
                End If
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's exacly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The leading zeroes are automatically removed in Excel by default. Thus `04,2014` is changed to `4,2014`. A way to work around this is to format the cells as Text, adding this line before the `Replace()`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Formatting to Text has a lot of unpleasant changes, e.g. the text goes to the left and Excel does not recognize the dates/numbers by default.

This is a simple sample of the code, changing 1 cell:

```
Sub TestMe()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("B5") = "05_2018"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("B5") = Replace(Range("B5"), "_", ".")
End Sub
```

---

Formatting to text can work like this, for bigger, unknown ranges:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Worksheets(1).Cells.NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("A1:B15") = "05_2018"

    Dim findRange As Range
    Set findRange = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find("_")
    Dim myCell As Range

    If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each myCell In findRange
            myCell.Replace "_", ","
        Next myCell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Even if you format the cells with `.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"`, you will still loose the leading zero :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - check the 4 lines in the sample.

Comment: I can confrim it looses 0. Formating to text is the first thing that i tried doing.

Comment: @Vityata: That is because you are using `Replace("", "_", ".")` like I did and not `.Cells.Replace` as your post originally mentioned :)

Comment: @JacekPotpaczuk - strange. 
With me the code above changes the `_` quite nicely to a `.` and the `0` stays. Also tried with a comma, same result (so it is not some date issue). Version 15 of Excel.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - my post did not change, I have only added the example. Still the `Replace()` makes the difference indeed.